# 406 (Not Acceptable) message returns from the service

Tags: asp.net, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm working on ASP.Net boilerplate  service project . I want to send a custom exceptions . I implemented

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class FriendlyError : ExceptionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
    {
        private readonly HttpStatusCode StatusCode;

        public FriendlyError(HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        {
            StatusCode = statusCode;
        }

        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            if (context.Exception == null) return;

            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)StatusCode;
            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "multipart/form-data;application/json";

            context.Result = new JsonResult(CreateErrorResult(context.Exception), new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                ContractResolver =  new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            });
            base.OnException(context);
        }
}
```

handle exceptions , and put the annotation on the  controllers endpoint. but it sends  406 (Not Acceptable) message to the client .

Comment: Is service WCF or rest services?

Comment: It  is a  web api rest service

Answer (score 0):

That is not unusual, You have got error **406 Not Acceptable** because you are returning an error not expected in  the list of acceptable values defined in `Accept-Charset` and `Accept-Language`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406 for more details.

I think you need to add something like :

```
context.HttpContext.Response.Charset = CharSet.Unicode;
```

and

`context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType` should be set based on type of response, generic `"multipart/form-data;application/json"` for every request might not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The MIME media type for JSON text is `application/json`. So change the content type.

**Recommendation**;

According to me you should check the result type of exception thrower action. If you always send json result, you might ignore other return types. ABP has `UserFriendlyException` which is neat! Why don't you use that?